# keyboard layout direction

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard-layout

I would like to detect the direction of the current typing (input) language.
I may detect the language by means of "GetKeyboardLayout", but then I'll have to check if it equals to Arabic or Hebrew and so on, is there any way just to detect the direction, i.e. left to right or right to left.

thanks!
mike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out: http://www.siao2.com/2006/03/03/542963.aspx